# Restlet - Access elements of the request URL

Tags: url, request, restlet

I'm unsure what the proper way is to access parts of the requested URL.

In this case, I want to get the requested path without the query variables.  This is the only way I found to do it:

```
String path = getRequest().getResourceRef().getHostIdentifier() + 
     getRequest().getResourceRef().getPath();
```

The result would be the bold part of this url: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask**?query=value

I also found about 6 different ways to get the server name (**http://stackoverflow.com**) but I'm worried that some of them would fail in certain cases that I am unaware of (why would there be 6 different ways to do one thing):

```
getRequest().getHostRef().getHostIdentifier();
getRequest().getHostRef().getIdentifier();
getRequest().getRootRef().getHostIdentifier();
getRequest().getRootRef().getIdentifier();
getRequest().getResourceRef().getHostIdentifier();
```

And this seems to get the complete URL with query parameters:

```
getRequest().getResourceRef().getIdentifier();
```

Any further explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're in a UniformResource (or subclass) I think you might be looking for the method getReference(), which returns the URI reference.  There are a number of other convenience methods in that class you might be interested in so you don't have to go through the request.  See [UniformResource](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/jee/api/) (Restlet 2.0).